# Linux repeatedly scrambles portions of the filesystem on NVME

Tags: debian, filesystems, linux-kernel, bugs, nvme

I have an NVME device holding the `/` ext4 partition and a few extra partitions for other operating systems and `/boot/efi`. Repeatedly, the file system gets corrupted, to the point where the already running bash doesn't even find the `shutdown` binary anymore, as if `/` was unmounted. While rebooting, fsck and friends appear to be able to repair the damage to the partition (so far!), cleaning up orphaned nodes and so forth, but this is still a problem. Especially since I'm not sure if other partitions are affected as well or if data is being destroyed without me realising it.

Is this a known problem? A friend suggested that there were issues with some kernel versions and NVME but I don't know what to do about it.

I'm running debian buster with the kernel version: 4.18.6-1.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I seem to have a similar problem on my dell xps laptop

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @xaxa: However, it did eventually end up destroying the installation and I had to reinstall.